# Yii2 : Can I set access behavior before authenticator?

Tags: php, yii2, behavior

```
protected $allowActions = ['login'];

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['access'] = [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
            [
                'roles' => ['@'],
                'ips'   => ['192.168.1.222'],
                'allow' => true
            ]
        ],
    ];
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
        'optional' => ['*'],
        'authMethods' => [
            [
                'class' => AutoLoginAuth::className()
            ],
            [
                'class' => JwtAuth::className(),
                'key'   => '89794c5c8f80bdd4916b4b8b7f9a044a'
            ]
        ],
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

I have two authMethods in authenticator and one ip rules in access behavior ,

I want to verify access ip rule behavior befor authenticator .

but authenticator`s verification always before access .

**How can I do to change the order of verification ?**

If you cannot handle this question .

Can you vote for more developers to see this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved, while authenticator is for authentication, the access behavior is for authorization.

Comment: OK , Thank you very much .@Isitar

Comment: why don't you define it as another authenticator class in your composite auth?

Comment: @mmta41. Composite auth classes must implement AuthInterface.but I want to use AccessControl . and AccessControl no need to implement it . They are two completely different verification methods .

Answer (score 0):

I found a new way to do this.

bootstrap.php

```
Yii::$container->set('yii\rest\Controller', 'refactoring\rest\Controller');
```

refactoring\rest\Controller.php

```
namespace refactoring\rest;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'contentNegotiator' => [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                'application/xml' => Response::FORMAT_XML,
            ],
        ],
        'verbFilter' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => $this->verbs(),
        ],
        'access'=>[
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        ],
        'authenticator' => [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
        ],
        'rateLimiter' => [
            'class' => RateLimiter::className(),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Code as above .

Injecting a new override class,Just set access before authenticator .

**To summarize:**

***First.***

I got access verification every times before authenticator **in this app** .This solution works for my needs .

***Second.***

If you want to use this method, please confirm if this method is used .

***Third.***

AccessControl had authenticator verification . This is yiisoft reasonable set authenticator before access . So this method is not suitable for everyone . I will do more authenticator verification in my reflecting class.